# Mouse listener while over an object (like a swf)?

Tags: javascript, html, flash, mouse, listener

I noticed that the mouse event I set up for firefox with javascript (document.onmousemove=move;) works fine whenever the mouse is not over an object such as a swf file

How can I get it so that it will work always, or even for the swf exclusively?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think events from a Flash object will bubble up to the DOM because they are in different contexts.